# Can I get my upvote unlocked?

Tags: support, voting

I was just looking through my rep list and I noticed a ding of -1. Apparently [for this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/114141/572), which I'm pretty sure I upvoted originally, because I *literally* say that in the comments. Somehow some Javascript or scrolling thing turned my upvote into a downvote.

Is it possible to reset my vote on that answer so I can properly upvote it?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to reset my vote on that answer so I can properly upvote it?

It would be **if the post got edited**, moment in which you would be able to re-cast your vote on the answer.

However, editing just for you to be able to change your vote doesn't seem a proper course of action to me... unless the post could use some edits in first place.

I suggest that you *just let it be*; it's 1 rep after all (and 2 for the answerer), so nothing that an approved edit or upvote received can't solve. I too have sometimes miss-clicked a post, but when I do I try to immediately change it (as you have a period in which you can freely do so).

Next time try perhaps double checking the vote action you casted, to avoid further incidents.

Comment: plus a -1 to your rep is a drop in the ocean if you participate here with any regularity